# Google maps iOS SDK level of detail polylines

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Google Maps iOS SDK to draw a list of polylines. The polylines come from a server, and for each next polyline, the starting point corresponds with the end point of the previous polyline.

I notice that Google Maps changes the level of detail of the polylines at different zoom levels, probably an optimisation thing. This results in small gaps between the several polylines at lower zoom levels.

The reasons behind splitting a polyline up in several smaller lines are not up to me, this is what the system defines for me. I know I may be able to combine the several polylines into one single large polyline, but I was wondering: does the SDK allow the setting for this level of detail? Or is there maybe another fix?

Zoomed out, notice the gaps:

[image]

Almost fully-zoomed in, the gaps are nearly gone:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code about how your draw the polyline in your screenshot?

Comment: Currently it is just a loop over a list of objects containing Google Encoded Polyline data, parsing the encoded poly data to a GMSPath, and creating a GMSPolyLine out of it:

    for (Link *link in links) {  
        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:link.polyData];  
        GMSPolyline *line = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];  
        line.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.7 blue:0.1 alpha:1];  
        line.strokeWidth = 4;  
        line.map = mapViewG;  
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no answer so far, so what I did, was traversing all geo-coordinates in-order (luckily my data-structure allows this), collect them in an array, encode this array to a Google Encoded Polyline (GEP) as per https://gist.github.com/mmdumi/3999640, and then display this on the map using [GMSPolyLine polylineWithPath:]. As far as I can tell, there is no way to instantiate a GMSPolyLine other than using a GEP.

Comment: did you find anything related to this topic? i'm having the same problem. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455063/google-maps-polyline-not-rendering-perfectly?noredirect=1#comment72185360_42455063 i faced the same problem checkout

Answer (score 0):

I have found no answer too, but, there are two ways :

1. You can draw the entire line like a for sentence and draw, for example :

   path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude_,longitude: longitude_))
               let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
               polyline.strokeColor = .red
               polyline.map = mapView
               polyline.strokeWidth = 2

or

2. https://github.com/raphaelmor/Polyline