# Google maps polyline not rendering perfectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing polyline using latest google maps API for iOS. I am constructing polyline point by point but it is not rendering properly as when i zoom out the polyline vanishes(not in literal terms) from the map and when i zoom in it simply shows the line.

[image: Zoomed in view]
This is how polyline appears when zoomed in

[image: Zoomed out view]
This is how it appears when zoomed out

here is my function for drawing polyline

```
RCPolyline *polyline = [[RCPolyline alloc] init];
[polyline drawPolylineFromPoint:self.selectedEmployee.location toPoint:location];
```

i have override `init:` for RCPolyline to be something like this

```
- (instancetype)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.strokeWidth = 5.0f;
    self.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor;
    self.geodesic = YES;
    self.map = [RCMapView sharedMapView];
}
return self;}
```

and `drawPolylineFromPoint:toPoint:` does this

```
 - (void)drawPolylineFromPoint:(CLLocation *)pointX toPoint:(CLLocation *)pointY {
      GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
      [path addCoordinate:pointX.coordinate];
      [path addCoordinate:pointY.coordinate];
      self.path = path;}
```

Comment: I guess your polyline path data is too much.

Comment: @wf9a5m75 and how is that related to this?

Comment: Drawing point of path uses memory. Lots of points means the Google Maps SDK for iOS uses lots of memory. I guess that's the reason.
In order to reduce your points, you can encode your path.
Check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393067/google-maps-ios-sdk-level-of-detail-polylines

Comment: @wf9a5m75 i solved my problem and i have provided the answer inclusion where i went wrong but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the glitch, i was making local instance of `RCPolyline` class and was calling the method for constructing polyline from that what i wanted was to have a global object for RCPolyline instance and update the `GMSPath` for the `RCPolyline` class instance

something like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithMap:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      self.strokeWidth = 4.0f;
      self.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
      self.geodesic = YES;
      self.map = mapView;
      self.mutablePath = [GMSMutablePath path];
    }
      return self;}
```

and now i am calling this method from that same instance.

```
- (void)appendPolylineWithCoordinate:(CLLocation *)location {
    [self.mutablePath addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
    self.path = self.mutablePath;}
```

PS: `RCPolyline` is subclass of `GMSPolyline`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
- (void)fetchPolylineWithOrigin:(CLLocation *)origin destination:(CLLocation *)destination {

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude:longg zoom:12];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView;
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.map = mapView;
    NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *directionsAPI = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving&key=%@&alternatives=true", directionsAPI, originString, destinationString,@"YOUR API KEY"];
    NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *fetchDirectionsTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
                                                 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                 {
                                                     NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                     if(error)
                                                     {
                                                         return;
                                                     }
                                                     NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
                                                     GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
                                                     int i=1;
                                                     for (id route in routesArray)
                                                     {
                                                         NSDictionary *routeDict = [route valueForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
                                                         NSString *points = [routeDict objectForKey:@"points"];
                                                         GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];
                                                         GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
                                                         polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                                                         polyline.strokeWidth = 3;
                                                         if(i==1)
                                                         {
                                                             polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];

                                                         }else if(i==2)
                                                         {
                                                             polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
                                                         }else{
                                                             polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                         }
                                                         i = i+1;

                                                         bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];
                                                         polyline.map=mapView;
                                                     }
                                                 }];
    [fetchDirectionsTask resume];
}
```

Comment: I am not using API to get route between two coordinates I am recording location data as the user is moving and plotting it